# Route53 API issue

Tags: .net, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

We are using Route53 .Net API to assign DNS. Actually most of the times we don’t face any issues at all, but lately and some time in the past we receive this type of issue as follows

"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

We are trying to support all SSL and TLS while connecting. We are trying to wait for some time and recall again , but sometimes we cannot avoid this issue and it is like there is some times this issue start to come like everyday and every second, and then suddenly it stops showing for another period of time.
Please if you can help us in finding a way to avoid this issue completely.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Honestly it sounds like an issue you should direct to AWS support.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Might also have API issues ! Also there is some limit on number of API's you can execute per hour.